# Recursive import Java

Tags: java

I am a newbie to Java development. I have a quick question regarding recursive imports in Java.

Lets assume Package "pkg" contains the following

- class A,
- package B (This in turn contains B1 class)
- package C (This in turn contains C1 class)

If I use `import pkg.*` why am I not allowed to import classes from packages "B" and "C" ?.

I would like to understand the rationale behind in Java's not allowing me to do recursive imports.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. There isn't really much of a relationship between packages, the apparent hierarchy notwithstanding; the fact that you have `pkg` and `pkg.B` doesn't really relate them in any useful way. What class are you trying to import to, and what do you mean by "not allowed to"?

Comment: What's wrong with doing that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is poorly phrased, because if you `import pkg.*`, you certainly are allowed to then import classes from packages `pkg.B` and `pkg.C`. That is, it is perfectly fine to do this:

```
import pkg.*;
import pkg.B.*;
import pkg.C.*;
```

But I assume that what you really are asking is why, if you `import pkg.*` it does not automatically import the types declared in the subpackages of `pkg`. To answer that, it's best to turn to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.1):

> The hierarchical naming structure for packages is intended to be convenient for organizing related packages in a conventional manner, but has no significance in itself other than the prohibition against a package having a subpackage with the same simple name as a top level type (§7.6) declared in that package.
>
> <sub>For example, there is no special access relationship between a package named `oliver` and another package named `oliver.twist`, or between packages named `evelyn.wood` and `evelyn.waugh`. That is, the code in a package named `oliver.twist` has no better access to the types declared within package `oliver` than code in any other package.</sub>

In other words, when you `import pkg.*`, you are importing all the top-level *types* defined by the compilation units contained in the package named `pkg`, but you are *not* importing any of the sub-packages of `pkg` (such as `pkg.B` or `pkg.C`).

Comment: Cleared my doubts..Tx

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're asking why `import java.awt.*` doesn't also import `java.awt.color.*` and so on.

This is best explained by [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) where it says

> At first, packages appear to be hierarchical, but they are not. For
>   example, the Java API includes a java.awt package, a java.awt.color
>   package, a java.awt.font package, and many others that begin with
>   java.awt. However, the java.awt.color package, the java.awt.font
>   package, and other java.awt.xxxx packages are not included in the
>   java.awt package. The prefix java.awt (the Java Abstract Window
>   Toolkit) is used for a number of related packages to make the
>   relationship evident, but not to show inclusion.

More importantly,

> Importing java.awt.* imports all of the types in the java.awt package,
>   but it does not import java.awt.color, java.awt.font, or any other
>   java.awt.xxxx packages. If you plan to use the classes and other types
>   in java.awt.color as well as those in java.awt, you must import both
>   packages with all their files:
>
> ```
> import java.awt.*;
> import java.awt.color.*;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The convention in Java is to import only the classes you required. Most IDEs will automatically organise them for you. Importing classes in bulk is not common like in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction on imports as you described *in your original question (prior to the edit)*.

Let's assume you have the following Hierarchy:

```
pkg1
    A.java
pkg1.pkg2
    B.java
pkg1.pkg3
    C.java
    D.java
```

You are permitted to import any of the A.java, B.java, C.java, D.java, or combinations therein.

```
import pkg1.A;
import pkg1.pkg2.B;
import pkg1.pkg3.C;
import pkg1.pkg3.D;
```

The only caveat is that within class C, you can use class D *without importing D explicitly* because they share the same package.

However, a blanket statement like `import pkg1.*` will not pull in the classes located further down the package hierarchy; you'd need to import each sub-package as well: `import pkg1.pkg2.*`, etc. This is simply how the language is designed.

Comment: There is no package hierarchy. `my.package` is totally different from `my.otherpackage`

Comment: That's nice? And obvious? I have no idea what you mean by your comment on a four year old answer. Please read the last paragraph. A package is independent of all other packages.