# Are Java packages nested, not nested... both?

Tags: java, import

I'm confused about importing packages in Java.

When I need to `import java.util.Scanner` , it is also done by the import statement like this: `import java.util.*` (this makes sense to me, as the `Scanner` class is in inside `util`).

But this trick works for `java.awt.event` and `java.awt.*` . This makes me more confused. (If your answer is that Java packages are not nested, please tell me the reason why the above tricks works. And if Java has both nested and independent packages how i can find them?

Comment: What "above trick" exactly? It would help if you could give a full concrete example of what you mean about java.awt.event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive import Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245483/recursive-import-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import wildcards are not recursive.

Importing `java.awt.*` does **NOT** import anything from `java.awt.event`. It only imports the classes in `java.awt`, not its "subpackages".

It should also be noted that importing a package doesn't actually **do** anything, it simply tells Java where to look for the class names you use.

Also, using wildcards is a bit sloppy anyway. You should probably be importing only the classes you actually use.

Edit: This question has been asked before: [Recursive import Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245483/recursive-import-java) and a quick google search of "java recursive import package" turns up a whole bunch of results, including:

[The Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html):

> At first, packages appear to be hierarchical, but they are not. For
>   example, the Java API includes a `java.awt` package, a `java.awt.color`
>   package, a `java.awt.font` package, and many others that begin with
>   `java.awt`. However, the `java.awt.color` package, the `java.awt.font`
>   package, and other `java.awt.xxxx` packages are not included in the
>   `java.awt` package. The prefix `java.awt` (the Java Abstract Window
>   Toolkit) is used for a number of related packages to make the
>   relationship evident, but not to show inclusion.
>
> Importing `java.awt.*` imports all of the types in the `java.awt` package,
>   but it does not import `java.awt.color`, `java.awt.font`, or any other
>   `java.awt.xxxx` packages. If you plan to use the classes and other types
>   in `java.awt.color` as well as those in `java.awt`, you must import both
>   packages with all their files:
>
> import `java.awt.*`; import `java.awt.color.*`;

And the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.1):

> The hierarchical naming structure for packages is intended to be
>   convenient for organizing related packages in a conventional manner,
>   but has no significance in itself other than the prohibition against a
>   package having a subpackage with the same simple name as a top level
>   type (§7.6) declared in that package.
>
> For example, there is no special access relationship between a package
>   named `oliver` and another package named `oliver.twist`, or between
>   packages named `evelyn.wood` and `evelyn.waugh`. That is, the code in a
>   package named `oliver.twist` has no better access to the types declared
>   within package `oliver` than code in any other package.

Comment: is it you mean that java.awt.* imports java.awt.events only but not java.awt.events.something ?

Comment: Importing java.awt.* imports all of the classes in java.awt, but none of the "subpackages" such as java.awt.event. See my edited answer for more information.

Comment: did you mean to avoid using regular expression in import statesments

Comment: Huh? You can't use regular expressions in import statements. Have you read the tutorials and the JLS?

Comment: sorry kevin i mentioned the * as the regular expression above

Comment: yeah , now understand that they represents the hierarchical convenient not the inclusion . And hence a.b.* includes only the classes under the a.b package not a.b.c package . is it am i right?

Comment: That's correct. Have you tried compiling a basic test example to test your theories?

Comment: yeah i have download the jdk x64 package from oracle site and placed it in directory and set javahome , classpth and path in bash.bashrc .

Comment: i tried the above and then run a sample hello world program , like placing my program in file myclassname.java located in class path . and then doing "javac myclass.java" then java myclass . it works. but all i did is just follow the tutorial . but what is happening is like a mystery.

Answer (score 2):

Package is Java's way to organize class files. Import a parent package will just import classes present inside that package, NOT the sub-packages.

Thus, to conclude, `java.awt.*` will import only `java.awt.<Class>` and NOT `java.awt.event.<Class>`

There is not a performance or overhead cost to doing import `<package>.*` vs importing specific types. However, it is considered to be a best practice to never use import `<package>.*` Basic reason for this is to keep things straight, clean and with as little ambiguity as possible, and with a `<package>.*` import you lose that.

Consider you have imported `java.lang.reflect.*` & `java.sql.*`, both the packages have `Array` class. You will end up in ambiguous situation. Hence you should avoid that and import `java.lang.reflect.Array` & `java.sql.Array` individually.

Shishir

Comment: thank you shishir . in import statements a.b.c  , is both a and b and c are package names . is it know which are package names and which are classes?

Comment: No Vignesh, you can't import just the package. Import statements expect classes.

Comment: oh thanks shishir , so the in x.y.z the z is a class inside package x.y

Answer (score 0):

Java packages look like they are hierarchical, but they are not. Each package name is just a dot seperated word list which defines a namespace. All namespaces together are not hierarchical, but flat, all at the same level.

Hence the notation `import a.b.c.*` means import all types defined by the package `a.b.c`, while `import a.b.c.Z` means import type `Z` defined by package `a.b.c`.