# What's the difference between import java.util.*; and import java.util.stream.*;?

Tags: java, import

I'm using Java 8's `Stream` functionality to manipulate the contents of an array in my program:

```
Obstacle[] closestObstacles = Stream.generate(() -> new Obstacle()).limit(8).toArray(Obstacle[]::new); // one for each line of attack
```

When I try importing `Stream` like this: `import java.util.*;` I get a "the symbol Stream cannot be resolved" error. When I instead import `Stream` like this: `java.util.stream;` things work as expected. Why does this happen? I don't use `Stream` or anything named "stream" elsewhere in my program, so I don't think it's a name conflict?

Comment: I doubt that the second attempt works. Maybe you `import java.util.stream.*;`? If you import with a wildcard, only the direct classes in this package will be imported, **not** the classes in sub-packages. Thus with an `import java.util.*`, you import all classes and interfaces listed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html). The class `Stream` actually resides in the [`java.util.list.stream` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Comment: Indeed - importing `java.util.stream.*` would import everything in the `java.util.stream` package. Importing `java.util.stream` would fail: `error: cannot find symbol`

Comment: You probably have some other `Stream` class imported somewhere (or you have a `Stream` class in you package), otherwise the `import java.util.*;` would have worked perfectly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive import Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245483/recursive-import-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt that the second attempt (`import java.util.stream;`) works. As [JonSkeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)  pointed out [in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038250/whats-the-difference-between-import-java-util-and-import-java-util-stream/48038317#comment83046803_48038250), it should result in a compilation error: `error: cannot find symbol`. Maybe you wanted to `import java.util.stream.*;`?

---

To the actual question:

If we import with a wildcard, that is the asterisk (`*`) character, **only the direct classes in this package will be imported, not the classes in sub-packages**. Thus with an `import java.util.*`, we import classes like [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html), [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).  A full list can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html). The class `Stream` actually resides in the sub-package [`java.util.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and is not imported when you `import java.util.*;`.

To import `Stream`, we can either `import java.util.stream.*;` (all classes within this package) or only `import java.util.stream.Stream;` (the FQDN of the class we need).