# Why importing java.util.* is not enough to import stream?

Tags: java, import, java-8, java-stream

## Short Version:

I understand that it's a bad practice to import `*` and it's best to import what exactly we need explicitly. However, I'm curious why importing `util.*` does not include `util.stream.*`.

## Long Version:

If I `import java.util.stream.*;`

this piece of code works successfully:

```
int[] a = {3, 4, 1};
ArrayList<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(a)
                          .boxed()
                          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

However, if I remove the `stream` from the `import`:

```
import java.util.*;
```

It fails:

```
Main.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
                                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable Collectors
  location: class Ideone
1 error
```

I have tried with Java 8 (1.8.0_201):

https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler

Java 11 (11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04):

https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/online-compiler/

and Java 12 (12.0.1+12):

https://ideone.com/7XfIFY

Comment: That's simply the way the language is designed. Though I can hazard a guess as to why it was designed that way: To limit the scope. For the behavior you expect to occur, importing `java.util.*` would import all of `java.util`, `java.util.stream`, `java.util.regex`, `java.util.zip`, `java.util.jar`. `java.util.cocurrent`, `java.util.concurrent.atomic`, `java.util.concurrent.locks`, `java.util.function`, and `java.util.spi`. That'd be a little ridiculous, no?

Comment: Already answered there
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038250/whats-the-difference-between-import-java-util-and-import-java-util-stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `wildcard import` that imports all the classes inside the package `not the sub-packages inside it`.

```
import java.util.*;
```

The above import statement will import all the [Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) inside the java.util package not the sub-package i.e `java.util.stream`
,So in order to import it, you need to have import statement like

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
```

[Read more on Importing packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Although the package name looks more like a manifestation of a hierarchical relationship, but they are not.

The package name is most like a prefix for the class.

For specific instructions, please refer to the [official document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)(Apparent Hierarchies of Packages)