# Why Collectors needs to be imported seperately from "java.util.*" package?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

To use collectors class methods like ***Collectors.toList()*** , we need to import java.util.stream.Collectors;
I have found that Collectors is a class and not a package as an answer at some places. But I still don't understand even if Collectors is a class, it is still part of java.util.* . Then why it needs to be imported seperately.

Comment: It's part of `java.util.stream.*`.

Comment: Because, as you say, it's part of `java.util.stream`, not `java.util`. `import java.util.*` means "import all the classes directly under the `java.util` package". It's not recursive.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245483/recursive-import-java

Comment: Packages in Java are not nested, even if their names suggest it. From a technical perspective `java.util.stream` is as connected to `java.util` as `java.nio` is: not at all. Just because they share a prefix doesn't mean that one "contains" the other.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the import of `java.util.stream` package you only import classes at the directory level specified. If you want to import classes at the level below this, you need to import that package directory as well. The import call does not recursively import everything from all directories and below, it only imports what you ask for at the level specified.